# Cisco Packet Tracer Hub IP

Tags: cisco, ip, packet-tracer

The problem that I'm facing has to do with the labeling above the hub's. I tried every possible hub in Packet Tracer and none of them had the configuration for IP. My guess is that the IP given is the IP of a VLAN or a Subnet. Can someone confirm me this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hubs are bacically powered cables. They do not know anything about VLANs or IP.

Comment: Then what does the IP above the hub represent?

Comment: Zac explained that.

Comment: I'm dumb and I don't understand it!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A label like `10.0.4.0/24` doesn't indicate a device IP address but a *network address* for the segment/subnet/VLAN running over that device. You can tell by the host part (fourth octet for /24) being all zero.

Comment: And how about configuring the VLAN? Should I do that in the Hub itself or somewhere else?

Comment: A (repeater) hub is entirely agnostic of higher-layer concepts like VLANs or even frames. You can picture a hub as a powered cable. Usually, hubs are entirely unmanaged. You configure VLAN connectivity (participating access and trunk ports) on the connected switches, and the L3 addressing on connected hosts and routers.